# list files in folder and sub-folders but with filenames concatenated with the file location

Tags: files, find

I am using Linux and I want to create a list of files stored in folder and sub-folders with the filenames and their absolute locations concatenated as one string e.g. (`/A/B/C/file.ext`)
some modification of:

```
ls -lR $PWD/* | awk '{printf(" %s/%s\n", ENVIRON["PWD"], $9); }'
```

to produce output where the PWD "current location" is replaced with the files absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Just use find.

```
find $(pwd) -type f -not -path '*/\.*'
```

This lists all the files in the cwd with their full paths

Comment: Why the `-not` part?  This would exclude hidden files, which wasn't stated by the OP.

Comment: because they did not state that there should be absolute file paths with . , and that may cause some more trouble for OP

Comment: More to the point, @bxm, the command used by the OP will exclude hidden files, so it is reasonable to provide alternatives that would produce the same output.

Comment: [Quote right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

Comment: That assumes that the current working directory doesn't contain space, tab, newline or wildcard characters and is not hidden itself. With some `find` implementations, that can fail to exclude hidden files / dirs whose name is encoded in a charset different from that of the current locale. Note that it still descends into hidden dirs even if it excludes all files in there for output.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 ~0/**/*(ND)
```

Would `print` `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn the paths of all non hidden files in `~0` (same as `$PWD`) sorted lexically. You could do the same with GNU `find` and `sort` with:

```
LC_ALL=C find "$PWD" -mindepth 1 -name '.*' -prune -o -print0 |
  sort -z |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

That assumes however that the base name of `$PWD` does not start with `.`.

On FreeBSD, you'd be able to do:

```
find "$PWD" -depth +0 '(' -name '.*' -prune -o -print0 ')' |
  sort -z |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```